# Images displaying different on Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, png, photoshop

I have a simple responsive landing page that is displaying a .png image like this:

[image: malformed image]

It looks like this on other devices and destop:

[image: correct image]

I tried to re-slice the image out in Photoshop, but It still displays the same way. I have no clue where to go next to try and correct this issue.

Here is the image I am currently using:

> [image: transparent png]

Comment: While, not a long term solution, what happens if you do a JPEG? How many bits per pixel is the PNG file? Can you save it with a different number of bits per pixel? Can you try making it an interleaved PNG?

Comment: Can you upload the original PNG somewhere so we can take a look at its structure? (Not sure your second "is" the actual same file.)

Comment: was the png exported in CMYK mode or RGB mode?

Comment: @Asif: that does not matter. [PNG does not support CMYK](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#4Concepts.ColourSpaces) and so Photoshop would convert it to RGB anyway. There is no difference in the produced PNG.

Comment: If I use a .jpg image it looks fine however it need to have a transparent background. It is a 256 bits per pixel, at 72 ppi. Same thing happens if I lower it to 158 bits. Interlaced doesn't help at all. I'll add the original image. Thanks for your help.

Comment: (Intermediary results) I compressed the original with Apple's modified `pngcrush -iphone`, which converts the image in a non-standard way. It displayed normally on OSX, and Photoshop refuses to load it (which is also "normal"). De-frying it back into a 'regular' PNG returned the original image again. So it seems not-reproducable on a desktop, alas.